# Joomla! 3 multi language content switching

Tags: plugins, joomla, multilingual

Many visitors visiting our website by a link to content in a different language from their mother tongue. If they click on the language switcher, they will be redirected to the home link of the current menu. That means they have to navigate to the content again.

Is there a Plugin available that solve this problem?

The use should change the language and see the english version of the specific content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not be the case, if you have set up bi/multi language in the right way.

Have you associated the articles to each others as well as the menu entrys? 
You need to have exact copies of your menu.

Are you talking about "Content Pages" that have no menu entry? If so, try to create a menu which is not visible for the user, but use it to associate content.

You find the Association Tab in the Menu Entry Edit

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I can also recommend to use the Multilanguage Status module. This helps to debug problems with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[The Falang component allows you to manage all your content translations, even the content of all your components/modules, on your web site.](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content/18210)

Falang doesn't use the default language system of Joomla 2.5 and 3.3. You don't have to specify a language for each content article or menu item (which results in a huge amount of duplication). You don't need to create few menu copies, few articles/categories copies for different languages.

[Here is described how to use it](http://www.faboba.com/en/composants/falang/documentation/47-installation-and-configuration-languages-joomla-3.html)